# Query places api for business venues in given area which contain panoramas?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-street-view, panoramas

In my Android application I would like to have a list of business places that have panoramas in given area (lat,lng). Is that possible in current api?

I haven't found it in current api docs (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

Comment: There is a StreetViewPanorama api. Hope that helps. But I dont know if they can give you a business place https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanorama#nested-class-summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such result from Google Places API. The function of the API is to get details about the particular place itself, its coordinates and its type. However you can create a custom search result, having data which is similar to what you need.

1. Use the location request service to get the list of places around you. You can filter on what kind of places you need. Eg: restaurants, places of interest, public places and so on.
2. Once you have the list, you need to query each place to get its details and preferably its reviews, to get the user feedback to check if this place in particular has a panoramic view or not.
3. Finally query the reviews for words like 'fantastic panorama', 'great panoramic view!', 'great for photos' and so on.

It is a rather crude way of dealing with the complex problem you are facing, and mine is just an opinion-based way of doing it. However you need to take into consideration the amount of places you have around you, based on how busy the area is.